# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable при вызове zipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, zipfile

```py
import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'E:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете использовать.

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Текущая дата служит именем подкаталога в основном каталоге
today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
# Текущее время служит именем zip-архива
now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')

# Запрашиваем комментарий пользователя для имени файла
comment = input('Введите комментарий --> ')
if len(comment) == 0: # проверяем, введён ли комментарий
    target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'
else:
    target = today + os.sep + now + '_' + \
      comment.replace(' ', '_') + '.zip'
    
# Создаём каталог, если его ещё нет
if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today) # создание каталога
print('Каталог успешно создан', today)

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Выполняю задание из книги «A Byte of Python», и там, после этого кода, без примеров, сказано:

> Напишите этот код с использованием модуля [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) вместо
> `os.system`.

И я пишу, импортировал модуль zipfile, и, вместо `os.system`, добавил `zipfile`.

Выходит эта ошибка:

> ```
> Каталог успешно создан D:\backup5\20190715
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "back5.py", line 26, in <module>
>     if zipfile(zip_command) == 0:
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
> ```

Как я понял, я неправильно использую модуль zipfile.

```
import os
import time
# В задании которуе я выполняю, не импортируют zipfile
import zipfile

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать
source = ['C:\\surprise']
# Путь резервных копий
target_dir = 'D:\\backup5'

# Текущая дата служит именем подкаталога в основном каталоге
today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

# Текущее время служит именем для zip-файла
now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')

# Запрашиваем комментарий пользователя для имени файла
comment = input('Введите комментарий ==> ')
if len(comment) == 0:
    target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'
else:
    target = today + os.sep + now + '_' + \
        comment.replace(' ', '_') + '.zip'

# Создание каталога
if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today)
print('Каталог успешно создан', today)

# Использование команды zip для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = 'C:\\gnuwin\\bin\\zip.exe -qr {0} {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
# В задании, вместо "zipfile", написано "os.system"
if zipfile(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в ', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии не удалось')
```

Comment: используйте [zipfile.ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

Comment: В указанной строчке ты вызываешь модуль, а нужно вызывать функцию из модуля. См комметарий MaxU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать метод ZipFile с модуля zipfile. Т.е. "zipfile" - название модуля, обращение через точку "zipfile.ZipFile" вызывает метод с указанного модуля

UPD: Исправил логику в коде, должно работать, но возможны некоторые синтаксические ошибки, так как писал вне редактора

```
import os
import time
import zipfile

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ziph.write(os.path.join(root, file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = 'C:\\surprise'
    target_dir = 'D:\\backup5'

    now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')
    today = os.path.join(*[target_dir, time.strftime('%Y%m%d')])

    comment = input('Введите комментарий ==> ')
    if len(comment) == 0:
       target = os.path.join(*[today, now + '.zip'])
    else:
        target = os.path.join(*[today, now + '_' + \
        comment.replace(' ', '_') + '.zip'])

    if not os.path.exists(today):
        os.mkdir(today)
        print('Каталог успешно создан', today)

    try:
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zipdir(source, zipf)
        zipf.close()
        print('Резервная копия успешно создана в ', target)
    except:
        print('Создание резервной копии не удалось')
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам :) Теперь выводит другую ошибку 
Введите комментарий ==> d
Каталог успешно создан D:\backup5\20190716
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "back5.py", line 34, in <module>
    if zipfile.ZipFile(zip_command) == 0:
  File "C:\Users\JOKER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'zip -qr D:\\backup5\\20190716\\172148_d.zip C:\\surprise'."

Comment: @JOKER На сколько я понимаю, вы не правильно используете функцию ZipFile, она не принимает команду на создание архива. Она должна принимать аргументы, чтобы открыть сувществующий архив, или же создать новый пустой. 
Вот документация по этой функции: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects
Сейчас обновлю ответ, с примером запаковки

Comment: @JOKER Исправил ответ, попробуйте данный вариант, он поможет вам, если вы хотите использовать zipfile для создания архива. Если же вы планируете использовать сторонний архиватор, то можете вернуться к своему методу формирования cmd команды, но тогда zipfile вам не нужен вообще, нужно смотреть в сторону os.popen